# basic performance comparison

Tags: mysql

Do you know which table srtucture is better :

```
table user  
id  INT pk autoincrement  
name VARCHAR(255)  
email VARCHAR(255)  
statut TINYINT(4)
```

The statut can only hold 2 states : 1/2

OR

```
table user  
id  INT pk autoincrement  
name VARCHAR(255)  
email VARCHAR(255)   
statut VARCHAR(45)
```

The statut can only hold 2 states : active/inactive

I'm looking for the fastest way to do select statements such as

```
SELECT id, name, email   
FROM user  
WHERE statut=:statut
```

I read somewhere that "integer" types are generally processed faster
than "text" types
but for some other reasons I would prefer to store the statut
with the `VARCHAR` type.
Is there a way to use statut with `VARCHAR` type AND that it runs faster ?
Or is the first structure definitively the fastest ?

Comment: have a read here http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/01/24/enum-fields-vs-varchar-vs-int-joined-table-what-is-faster/#comment-624098 and this http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/08/09/picking-datatype-for-status-feilds/#comment-343318

Comment: thank you. Now I get unsure again about best approach...

Comment: Personally i use a one byte tinyint (0,'un-verified'),(1,'active'),(-1,'closed') as it allows you to add new status values without altering the table definition like the enum datatype, which for large tables can take hours !! If you're not concerned about that use an enum.

Comment: Yes, so enum is not sql standard, and I may have some difficulties with order on it or when I wish to extends the status. Since I may have other tables in which I'm not absolutely sure about the number of different status I will stick to the tinyint type with integer to string mapping.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ENUM` if you're absolutely sure that you'll only ever need to store 2 values in that column. Combines the user-friendliness of text with the performance and space-efficiency of integers.

Comment: You'd also be damn sure you never migrate to another DBMS as ENUM isn't standard SQL AFAIK. Of course there's always some changes required when migrating, but I'd rather minimize the amount of needed work than maximize it.

Comment: @pkauko Haha yeah, I was assuming MySQL. If it were something like Postgres, I would have suggested `bool` for only two possible values!